# Nested function within Data Validation Source Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, nested

Is it possible to create a drop down list that depends on another drop down list without having the actual data on a spreadsheet?

As an example, Lets say Cell A1 has a drop down list and within the data validation source I have written:

```
Building 1, Building 2, Building 3
```

Now in cell A2 I want a second dropdown list that takes into account what is in the first one. Within the source box for A2 I have tried two different codes. The first one is a simple IF statement:

```
=IF(A1="Building 1", "Office, Retail, Prison", IF(A1="Building 2", "School, Pre-School, Sixth Form", IF(A1="Building 3", "Higher Ed, Further Ed", "")))
```

This pops up the error message:

*The List Source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column*

Which I'm gathering it doesn't like the fact there are symbols in other than commas. I then tried a text join function:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF(A1="Building 1", "Office, Retail, Prison", IF(A1="Building 2", "School, Pre-School, Sixth Form", IF(A1="Building 3", "Higher Ed, Further Ed", "")))), ","))
```

However, Excel did not like this code saying there was a problem with it. I personally cannot see it but fresh eyes always help.

I know it is possible to easily do this by making a data column in the spreadsheet but I want to try to do this without that as it will look untidy.

Or will I have to hard code this in VC?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you define Data Validation list in Excel "The List Source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column", so it cannot be any array or text produced by a formula. But if you define Data Validation in VBA the list may be a text. 
If there are only texts or integers in the list, it can be done, only those texts cannot contain list separators. But, if there are decimal numbers in the list, there may be a separator conflict, depending on the locale.

Comment: I will have a go at doing in in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2-column list, as shown in F:G here.

For `A1`, the data validation should be the list of buildings.

For `A2`, create a second list, as shows in `I2` here, where you filter the first list based on the value of A1. The formula in `I2` is:

```
=FILTER($G$1:$G$8,$F$1:$F$8=$A$1)
```

This formula will return only the building types in column G, if the building type in column F matches the building type that has been selected in `A1`

Then, for your data validation in `B2`, use:

```
=$I$1#
```

Note the `#` at the end of the reference. This means it will not just read `I2`, but it will read all the values from the formula in `I2`, which is the list of buildings you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kevin, but as I said I am trying to do this without having the data on the actual sheet. Thank you though!

Comment: Ah ok. If the main concern is how it looks, also consider putting the data validation source on a different sheet, and hide or very-hide the sheet.